# GPO - Set Windows 10 domain desktop background but allow users to change

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, domain-controller

My DC is Windows S2008 r2 and i have a wallpaper policy set for all domain users. It works fine and the wallpaper shows up on all client computers.  I want to modify this so that my **Windows 10** clients (or any really) can *change* the background if they want to. I tried the recommendations in [this link](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/best-practice-using-group-policy-to-configure-desktop-wallpaper-background/) but they don't work for Windows 10 clients.

[Here is screen shot when user tries to change background picture (greyed out).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWPUA.png)

Is this customization via gpo possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that comes to mind, is to set the wallpaper's path to a user-writable location in the GPO.

Then, you can create a preference that copies your initial wallpaper **once** (`Common` tab -> `Apply once and do not reapply`) at this location and instruct the user to overwrite the image if they want.